# Detect if document update fails

Tags: vespa

This update-statement:

```
curl -v -X PUT 
  -d '{"fields":{"postings":{"assign":42}}}' 
  http://localhost:8080/document/v1/post/post/docid/ABCDEFG
```

Question:
The post "ABCDEFG" does not exist - but the server answers "200 OK".
Is there way to detect, that the update statement fails (e.g. getting a "404 NOT FOUND")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://docs.vespa.ai/en/reference/document-v1-api-reference.html

Going by the documentation that is expected behavior. Utilize the [condition](https://docs.vespa.ai/en/reference/document-v1-api-reference.html#condition) parameter to determine if the document exists first in order to get a 412 status code instead.